# Parser error copying a single aspx page with code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, copy, code-behind

When I just copy (without deploying) an aspx page with code-behind to a web site I get a Parser Error Message when I try to use the page.

Let us assume this is just for testing purposes that I want to develop a single page in Visual Studio then copy (or FTP) it to a web site.

The complete error message is:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SimpleSite.WebForm2'.
```

The WebForm2.aspx file is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs"
Inherits="SimpleSite.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The WebForm2.aspx.cs file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SimpleSite
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the namespace is the problem, it appears to be. I have used Expression Web to create an ASP.Net file with code-behind that I can just FTP
but that does not have a namespace (yes, I know; it is in the global namespace).

If I want to make one or two aspx files with code-behind just for educational purposes to be copied without deploying, can I do that using a Visual Studio Web Project or Web Site and maintain the page such that it still works as a page in the Visual Studio Web Project or Web Site?

Comment: You would need to do it as a Web Site, not a Web Application Project. And you would need to copy over any dependencies it has.

Comment: And that's because Web Site is compiled on the fly unlike Web App project.

Comment: @mason, do you **know** it will work as a web site or are you guessing? The code is the same whether I use a Web Project or Web Site to create it, but if I am missing something then please explain the difference. When I use a Web Site I get the same results. Also, I provided all the code. What part of the error message indicates there is something missing?

Comment: A Web Site does not have to have the .aspx.cs compiled before deploying, so yes I know it will work. The code should not be the same for a Web Site and a Web Application Project. If they're the same, then they're wrong.

Comment: @mason, if you are able to create a simple page like the one I showed in a web site and then copy it to a server and get it to work then I am sure interested in knowing how you did it.

Comment: There's not much to it. Just create a website (not a web application project) in VS and do an FTP deployment.

Comment: An FTP deployment is what I am explicitly asking how to avoid. The question is asking how to deploy just a single page, not the entire web site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the namespace is a problem.

Visual Studio creates pages for a Web Site without a namespace **specified**, in other words it creates pages with the code in the global namespace. Therefore simple pages (that do not use additional files) created in a VS Web Site can be copied individually by copying just the aspx file and corresponding aspx.cs file.

Another difference between a Web Project and a Web Site is that VS adds a aspx.designer.cs file for each page. It is not created for Web Sites.